# JavaScript 'this' in different context

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to create a JavaScript object as follows.

```
var MyObject = function (parameters) {
    this.parameters = parameters;
    parameters.userFunction(this.MyObjectCallback);
}

MyObject.SOME_STATIC_VARIABLE = 21;

MyObject.prototype = {
    myObjectCallback: function() {
         console.log(this);
    }
}
```

The `MyObject` object will accept a userFunction to which it will pass a handler. The user function will do some logic and pass the result back to the instance, for example:

```
new MyObject({userFunction: function(callback) {
   $.post(
        'http://localhost/~knyttl/source.php',
        {},
        callback,
        'json');,
}});
```

Unfortunately, even though the `callback` is properly called, `this` gets an instance of the `JQuery` object and not of the `MyObject` instance as I would like. To conclude, I can not manage to keep the `MyObject` instance.

I am not even sure, whether this is a correct way of creating JavaScript objects. I will be grateful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind a specific `this` value using `.bind`. Also I corrected the capitalizing of `My`.

```
parameters.userFunction(this.myObjectCallback.bind(this));
```

When you call a function like `a.b()`, then inside `b`, `this === a`. However, if you do *not* directly call it but only pass the function (like `a.b`) and call it later, this binding is lost.

`.bind` returns a new function which now receives the jQuery ajax result as `this`. However, it ignores that and calls `myObjectCallback` with the predefined (bound) `this`.

`.bind` is not available on older browsers but there are shims available.

Answer (score 0):

See [apply() and call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

```
parameters.userFunction.call(this, this.MyObjectCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery allows you to set the [**context**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) of your callback.

You are in a weird situation where you design has hurt you. Your MyObject can't be passed in as the context, because it is being created at the same time.

```
new MyObject({userFunction: function(callback) {
   $.post(
        'http://localhost/~knyttl/source.php',
        {},
        callback,
        'json');,
}});
```

So instead:

```
var myObj = new MyObejct();
myObj.setCallback({userFunction: function (callback) {
     $.ajax({
         context: myObj,
         url: 'http://localhost/what ever /',
         success: callback,
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {}
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
            var myObject = {

                obj1:function(paremeters){
                    this.Name = paremeters
                    return this},
                };
```

I would suggest you read,
http://javascript.crockford.com/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

Using **this** in javascript has the potential to be very confusing. It is assigned the value of whatever is behind the dot when the function is called e.g.

```
window.doSomething();
```

will cause **this** to be set to window, whereas

```
myDOMElement.onClick();
```

will cause **this** to be set to myDOMElement.

In your case, it comes down to JQuery's internal workings, so have a look at [this very thorough set of explanations](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/what-is-this) to get an understanding of how JQuery handles **this**.