# Meteor redraw sets "this" gets set to undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using meteor to display a list.

So I decided to add the ability to move items in a list around the page by adding up arrows to move an item up in a list.
This works the first time you click on the arrow but further attempts fail as the "this" is undefined now. So on click of the up arrow I do:

```
Template.experiment.events({

    'click .js-moveup': function(e, tpl){
        e.preventDefault();

        // Movethis item up one.
        Meteor.call("moveUp", this._id, this.info.url_id, this.info.order); 
        return false;
    },
});
```

The template looks like this:

```
   <template name="experiment">
    <div class="container">
        <form class="update">
            {{#each experiment}}
                <!-- triple makes  does not escape html -->
                {{{display info}}}
            {{/each}}
        </form>
    </div>
    </template>
```

(display info generates the required HTML for the item)

All moveup does is exchange the order fields for the one clicked and the one above it.

On first click the order changes as expected and those two items are redrawn (and have the correct data in them) BUT on further clicking the "this" in the event handler is undefined?

This came form a much larger piece I have been working on but I have hacked it now to its simplest form to make sure nothing else is interfering and I include this [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6kzclotsrfqe0t/testupdown.tar.gz?dl=0)

Any suggestions are very welcome as I am completely stumped now.

Perhaps my problem is how Meteor deals with updating.
Here is my router bit:-

```
Router.route('/experiment/:url_id', {
    template: 'experiment',
    subscriptions: function() {
        console.log("template render experiment")
        return [Meteor.subscribe('experiments',
                            {"meta.url_id":this.params.url_id}),
                Meteor.subscribe('experiment', this.params.url_id)];
    },
    action: function (){
        this.render('experiment');
    },
    data: function (){
        return {bob:"bobby"};
    }
});
```

So on initial drawing the data is correct, this contains the data i need
(from the  db "experiment").
After redrawing the data is {bob:"bobby"} (i put this in to make see what was happening) if i miss out data it gets set to undefined. So the wrong data is being imported/overwritten on redrawing.

UPDATE:
So my question is why Meteor loses the context after a redraw. If i use html 
(which is commented out) it works fine but using the function display (which generates the same html code) does not.

I have reduced this to two files :-
experiment.html
    
      Experiment item move

```
<body>
  {{> experiment}}
</body>
<template name="experiment">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Experiment...</h1>
     {{#each experiment}} 
        {{log}}
<!--          <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-sx-10">{{info.label}}</div>
          <div class= "col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-sx-2">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default js-moveup" data-id="{{_id}}"  name="{{info.label}}">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" data-id="{{_id}}" aria-hidden="true" name="{{info.label}}"></span></a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-sx-offset-2 col-sx-10">          
          <textarea class="js-text-input" rows="4" cols="50" name="{{info.label}}" type="textarea">{{info.value}}</textarea>
          </div> -->

          {{{display _id info}}}   <!-- triple makes  does not escape html -->
      {{/each}}
  </div>

</template>
```

and experiment.js:-

```
//experiment.js
Experiment = new Mongo.Collection('experiment');
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  function moveUpNew (mongo_id) {
    var clicked = Experiment.findOne({_id: mongo_id});
    var above = Experiment.findOne({"info.url_id": clicked.info.url_id, "info.is_current": 1, "info.order": clicked.info.order-1});
    if (above) { // One clicked could be the top one. hence there may not be one above
       Experiment.update({_id: clicked._id}, {$inc: {"info.order": -1}}); //move up one
       Experiment.update({_id: above._id},   {$inc: {"info.order":  1}}); // move down one
    }
  }; // end moveUpNew



  Template.experiment.helpers({

    // Get list of experiment to display and sort by latest first.
    experiment: function(data){
        return  Experiment.find({},{sort :{"info.order": 1, "info.created": 1}});
    },
    log: function () {
      console.log("LOG: ", this);
    },
    // Main display of the docs
    display: function(mongo_id, info) {
        console.log("INSIDE display ", mongo_id);
        console.log(info.label+" "+info.order);
        var html = '<div class="well row">';
          html += '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-sx-10">'+info.label+'</div>';
          html += '<div class= "col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-sx-2">';
            html += '<a href="#" class="btn btn-default js-moveup" data-id="'+mongo_id+'" name="'+info.label+'">';
            html += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" data-id="'+mongo_id+'" aria-hidden="true" name="'+info.label+'"></span></a>';
          html += '</div>';


          html += '<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-sx-offset-2 col-sx-10">';
          // simple text input area for text
          if ( info.type == "text" ) {
              html += '<textarea class="js-text-input" rows="4" cols="50" name="'+info.label+'"'+' type="textarea">'+info.value+'</textarea>';
          }
          html += "</div>"; // end text input
          html += "</div>"; // end well row
        return html;
    }


  });

  Template.experiment.events({

  'click .js-moveup': function(e, tpl){
     e.preventDefault(); 
    var data = Blaze.getData(e.currentTarget);
    console.log("data is");
    console.log(data);
 //   Meteor.call("moveUp", this._id, this.info.url_id, this.info.order);   // Move this item up one.
     moveUpNew(data._id);
  }

  });
} // end is MeteorClient
```

Comment: If you want somebody to help with your source code provide meteor code not bundle code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript 'this' in different context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431773/javascript-this-in-different-context)

Comment: `this` points to the `function` int is in not what you think it does so `this._id` is undefined for the context it is called in. This is asked over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over an

Comment: @JarrodRoberson that's correct in the javascript sense, but Meteor provides its own context to template related functions (helpers, event maps and lifecycle hooks) so the OP is right to be surprized there only because `each` is actually a template with its own bound context although not a proper one hence the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in event handlers is a little tricky. Instead, you should use the proper Blaze API.

What you are looking for is:

```
var data = Blaze.getData(e.currentTarget());
Meteor.call("moveUp", data._id, data.info.url_id, data.info.order);
```

Also, you can delete `return false` you don't need that.

Comment: var data = Blaze.getData(e.currentTarget);  gives me the wrong data. I have two templates experiments and experiment (maybe  should have had more differing names to make it easier to see). The template experiment displays the data for this okay but if i use the above Blaze line in the template.events processing  i get the data for the experiments and not the one from the template? Sorry fairly new to Meteor and it is in some terms a magic black box to me.

Comment: No problem, I'd like to help. But your question does not show the `experiments` template at all so I have no way to see how you are using it and how it affects the data context. Perhaps you should update the question with the complete codebase that is relevant to the question.

Comment: ah, actually after the redraw the data is set to {bob:"bobby"} so it seems to use the data routine on redrawing rather than the template experiment and looping around the experiment. Previously this was not set and i was getting undefined.

Comment: If i use html rather than getting a javascript function (display) to generate the html all is well with the world. Unfortunately the function is quite complicated and display all sorts of data (well the real one, rather the cut down one which i was able to reproduce just in html) so not sure how to proceed now.  I presume the {{{ (triple brackets) stops the data from binding on redrawing.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really can't help you with descriptions and pseudo code. I really need to see the actual code that's not working or a minimal reproduction.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7sfl4t35kqjw62/testupdown.zip?dl=0 contains my test code. The commented out html code in client/experiment.html works fine but  the function display generates the same html code but does not work.

Comment: Well, the way SO works, you share the complete question and the "relevant" pieces of code within the question body. Not links to zip files. I think you should read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

You could add data-* attributes to your info and use that.

```
Template.experiment.events({
    'click .js-moveup': function(e, tpl){
        e.preventDefault();
        $item = $(e.currentTarget)

        // Movethis item up one.
        Meteor.call("moveUp", $item.data('id'), $item.data('url_id'), $item.data('order')); 
    },
});
```

While your tag would have something like this:

```
<a class="js-moveup" data-id="{{_id}}" data-url_id="{{info.url_id}}" data-order="{{info.order}}">up_arrow</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, i can use this a work around until i work out why this is happening.

Comment: Nope, I advise seriously against it. Blaze already provides a data context and an API for that. Using html specific attributes is counterintuitive and prone to application lifecycle issues in terms code manageability and maintenance.